# Getting first month profits in a SQL table containing fx trade data

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a Oracle SQL table that contains all the FX trading information related to trades made by clients. An entry is created for the initial opening trade, and then another entry is created when that trade is closed. The second entry contains information relating to the profit/loss on that trade. The initial trade id is also captured in the second entry as 'initial_trade_id' (or is filled in with 0 if the entry is for the initial trade)

What I would like is to calculate the proportion of clients who made successful profitable trades within a month of their first trade. I only want to consider trades that have been closed and forget active ones.
The final result should answer this statement 'Of the clients who traded for a month since their first trade, X number were profitable overall, while Y number were loss making overall'

The table schema is like this (ignoring irrelavnt columns):

```
+--------------------------+
| TRADE_ID                 | 
| TRADE_TIMESTAMP          | => 'DD-MON-YY HH-MM-SS'
| CLIENT_ID                | 
| INITIAL_TRADE_ID         | => is 0 if entry is the initial trade or 'TRADE_ID' if closing trade
| TRADE_PROFIT_LOSS_AMOUNT | => can be positive or negative
+--------------------------+
```

An example pair of entries would be

```
+-------+----------------------+-----+-------+-----+
| ZXCVB | 12-JAN-2020 08.00.00 | 123 | ASDFG | 159 |
+-------+----------------------+-----+-------+-----+
| ASDFG | 01-JAN-2020 14.00.00 | 123 |     0 |   0 |
+-------+----------------------+-----+-------+-----+
```

My initial thinking of this was to use ROWNUM to get the first trade for every client, then look for close trades that are within a month of that first trade date, before taking an AVERAGE per client, then using a SUM and CASE  based on the positive/negative avg value to get the proportion of successful trades. However I am having trouble getting this query down, so any help would be appreicated.

At the end I'd like to end up with:

```
+----------------------------+--------------------------+
| PROFIT_MAKING_CLIENT_COUNT | LOSS_MAKING_CLIENT_COUNT |
+----------------------------+--------------------------+
|                        924 |                      459 |
+----------------------------+--------------------------+
```

i.e. if over a month a client's average TRADE_PROFIT_LOSS_AMOUNT is positive based upon all their closed trades, a count of one is added to PROFIT_MAKING_CLIENT_COUNT (and vice versa)

Comment: What does "overall" mean?  Any profitable trade or net positive?

Comment: @GordonLinoff By overall, I mean across all trades a client makes in the month after their first trade (e.g. if a client makes 10 trades, 6 losses and 4 profitable,  overall he is a loss maker) and then counting the relative amounts of people who are counted as successful or loss making

Comment: Please edit your question and include statements to set up and populate tables with test data. A pre-built [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18) would be helpful here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the first trade and then aggregate.  I'm not sure what the exact definition of the the flags is, but this seems to be the information you want:

```
select client_id,
       sum(TRADE_PROFIT_LOSS_AMOUNT) as profit_30_days,
       max(TRADE_PROFIT_LOSS_AMOUNT) as any_profit_30_days
from (select t.*, min(trade_timestamp) over (partition by client_id) as min_tt
      from t
     ) t
where trade_timestamp < min_tt + interval '30' day
group by client_id;
```

Comment: I think that's close to what I'm looking for, but not sure why you included the max amount. I updated my original question (right at the end) with a final result I would like to have. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When presented with a problem like this, the first thing to do is to break it down into individual elements. Your problem statement is:

> Of the clients who traded for a month since their first trade, X number were profitable >overall, while Y number were loss making overall

To get a list of the clients who have traded for at least one month you can use:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID,
       MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, MIN(TRADE_TIMESTAMP)) AS TRADING_MONTHS
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
  HAVING MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, MIN(TRADE_TIMESTAMP)) >= 1
```

Next, you need to sum up the profits and losses of the clients:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID
       SUM(TRADE_PROFIT_LOSS_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PROFIT_LOSS
  FROM YOUR_TABLE
  GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
```

Then derive the clients who are making and losing money as:

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID
  FROM cteClient_profit_loss
  WHERE TOTAL_PROFIT_LOSS > 0
```

and

```
SELECT CLIENT_ID
  FROM cteClient_profit_loss
  WHERE TOTAL_PROFIT_LOSS < 0
```

Then just count of the results of each subquery and put it all together and you get:

```
WITH cteActive_clients AS
       (SELECT CLIENT_ID,
               MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, MIN(TRADE_TIMESTAMP)) AS TRADING_MONTHS
          FROM YOUR_TABLE
          GROUP BY CLIENT_ID
          HAVING MONTHS_BETWEEN(SYSDATE, MIN(TRADE_TIMESTAMP)) >= 1),
     cteActive_client_count AS
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS ACTIVE_CLIENT_COUNT
          FROM cteActive_clients),
     cteClient_profit_loss AS
       (SELECT CLIENT_ID
               SUM(TRADE_PROFIT_LOSS_AMOUNT) AS TOTAL_PROFIT_LOSS
          FROM YOUR_TABLE
          GROUP BY CLIENT_ID),
     cteClients_profitable AS
       (SELECT CLIENT_ID
          FROM cteClient_profit_loss
          WHERE TOTAL_PROFIT_LOSS > 0),
     cteProfitable_client_count AS
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS PROFITABLE_CLIENT_COUNT
          FROM cteClients_profitable),
     cteClients_losing_money AS
       (SELECT CLIENT_ID
          FROM cteClient_profit_loss
          WHERE TOTAL_PROFIT_LOSS < 0),
     cteMoney_losing_client_count AS
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS MONEY_LOSING_CLIENT_COUNT
          FROM cteClients_losing_money)
SELECT PROFITABLE_CLIENT_COUNT,
       MONEY_LOSING_CLIENT_COUNT
  FROM cteProfitable_client_count
  CROSS JOIN cteMoney_losing_client_count
```